# How to compile down typescript while using personal and external modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I have a typescript project where I want to supplement my code with an imported library that was downloaded from npm. How can I compile all of this down to a single javascript file that includes all of my code *along with* the node library it depends on?

Basically:

- file1.ts (depends on file2.ts)
- file2.ts (depends on an external npm
  library)

compiles `file1.ts` + `file2.ts` + `external library` into a single `build.js` file

Answer (score 2):

This is referred to as "bundling"; TypeScript does not provide bundling for compilations that use module constructs like `import`, `export`, or `require`. You'll need to use a tool, such as webpack or rollup, to combine multiple modules into a single file.